# One element in array php , how to explode it?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of links:

```
('url1','url2','url3')
```

But sometimes it's going to be only one link e.g. `('url')`

So how do i have to get the url if its only one because i'm using explode with comma?

Comment: So you do not have an array of links but a string ?

Comment: `explode()` still works even if it only will produce an array with one element.

Comment: its an array but only with one element,how do i check if its empty? and if it is add a comma at the end?

Comment: array_filter() removes empty values from array

Comment: no, ,, i have an array with one element,how do i add comma , to the only elemant

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = "('url1','url2','url3')";
preg_match_all("~'(.*?)'~", $input, $output);
var_dump( $output);
//array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "'url1'" [1]=> string(6) "'url2'" [2]=> string(6) "'url3'" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "url1" [1]=> string(4) "url2" [2]=> string(4) "url3" } }
```

and

```
$input = "('url1')";
preg_match_all("~'(.*?)'~", $input, $output);
var_dump( $output);
//array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "'url1'" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "url1" } }
```

Comment: no, ,, i have an array with one element,how do i add comma , to the only elemant